# scrollTo a specific div on long scrolling page when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a long scrolling page with lots of divs, one below the other. i would like to scroll automatically when you visit (or reload) the site to scroll from top to a specific div near of the bottom. to jump there isnt a problem, but i want the "scroll" effect. ive checked out scrollTo() but i dont get it to work.
my first attempt was something like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.scrollTo('#div5'); });
```

but it doesnt fire anything. a little bit help needed :)
thanks

Comment: Just use `$('body').scrollTop($('#div5').offset().top);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#div5').offset().top
}, 500);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nTwLm/2/

Comment: It works as it should. It doesn't scroll to specified div for you?

Comment: no unfortunatly not. in your fiddle it should scroll to content37, it doesnt work neither. but you got my problem, thats exactly what i want...

Comment: and i used firefox! now i works like a charm, thank you very much for this!